# Character “^[[A” “^[[B” “^[[C” “^[[D” when pressing the arrow keys in pyspark 2.0

Tags: pyspark, ansi-escape

I am getting the characters `^[[A` `^[[B` `^[[C` `^[[D` when pressing the arrow keys in pyspark 2.0.
I have spark 1.6 and spark 2.0 installed on my virtual machine on Cent OS. There is no issue with spark 1.6.

Since I am using python 2.7 with pyspark 2.0, "pip2.7 install readline" is not working.
I tried

```
pip2.7 install pyreadline
```

But that is not fixing the issue.

Comment: These are ANSI escape sequences. `^[` stands for the escape character (ASCII 27), and the following includes the type and parameters of the sequence. Read more about them [on Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)

Comment: What is the output of `head -2 /path/to/SPARK-version-*/bin/pyspark`